# How to make UIButton to autozie itself on load

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I have a UIButton which can depending on localization show different text, its `numberOfLines` is set to `0` to allow more than one line. However if the storyboard is loaded its only changing the Label inside the button which becomes multi line if required. The button itself stays with its original height having the text exceeding its bound. (the button is inside a layout but I have no constraints restricting its height) If I connect its click event with `view.layoutIfNeeded()` it jumps into the right size. But how bring it to adjust itself properly on first load?

Comment: How you are setting your button title?

Comment: The title comes from Main.strings files of the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the text to your button you can do like

```
CGSize stringsize = [myString sizeWithFont:<YOUR BUTTON FONT>];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,stringsize.width, stringsize.height)];
```

Comment: The button can handle text and size itself. I just asking me what is preventing it to do it if the view is created. (I also don't see how this approach handles multiline)